# Error with a new project in Netbeans 8.2 and Symfony 2.8.13

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

I am created a Symfony2 project in NetBeans 8.2..

The project created successfully but NetBeans shows syntax errors in some of vendor package files.

1. Download netbeans 8.2(All) and install it.
2. Download "Symfony 2.8.13 with vendors" zip file.
3. Insert into tools-->optins --> PHP --> Frameworks tools -->Symfony/2/3
4. Created the project.

Errors are from 5 or 6 file on vendor package files..

[image]

Comment: What errors, that might help us

Comment: @RiggsFolly http://www.screencast.com/t/PxeuhzIBhXP

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/izdYD69H

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/cWLUezv8

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/pnVx4AprkUdo

Comment: What is your issue? Doublecheck the 'errors' - two are invalid by purpose and others are related to PHP 7 which you probably don't use in your case. So what is not working as expected?!

Comment: Are you using PHP7?

Comment: No  i use PHP 5.3